# Recursive math functions in Gosu #update

Tags: ruby, math, graphics, libgosu

Is there a way to continuously add (or perform any math function continuously) in Gosu. Update is called 60 times a second. Therefore, given the following code:

```
x = 0
x += 1
p x
```

I would expect a continuous output of:

```
=> 1
=> 2
=> 3
=> 4
# etc.
```

Instead I get

```
=> 1
=> 1
=> 1
=> 1
# etc.
```

Can anyone explain why this happens, and is there a way to get my expected result?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You're reassigning the `x` variable on every loop to 0. Changing your code to:

```
x ||= 0
x += 1
p x
```

Should get you the result you want.

The first line means if x has a value, do nothing and if it is nil, then assign it to 0.

Comment: Hmm...I definitely should have caught that. That should solve it, but it doesn't. I get the same result. Interestingly though, if I make x an instance variable and assign its value in initialize then use @x += 1, that works. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can I see all the code involved in the loop please? Don't think I've enough to go on

Comment: `require 'gosu'

class Test < Gosu::Window
    def initialize
        super 640, 480, :fullscreen => false
        self.caption = "test"

        @x = 0
    end

    def update
        y ||= 0
        y += 1
        puts "y = #{y}"

        @x += 1
        puts "x = #{@x}"
    end
end
 Test.new.show`